# Generate PDF, sized for iPhone viewing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, pdf

I have a mac app that will also be an iphone app, that will  generate PDF's that are optimised for reading on an iPhone. Apple provide some useful sample code demonstrating how to do this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#samplecode/PDFCalendar/Listings/CalendarPage_m.html

However the page size in points is not the right shape for an iPhone screen. Does anyone know the scorrect size to use on the iphone.

```
- (NSRect) boundsForBox: (PDFDisplayBox) box
{
    // Always return 8.5 x 11 inches (in points of course).
    return NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0);
}
```

Comment: iPhone has 320x480 (even for retina display) and iPad has 1024x768 resolution (portrait for both devices, just swap these two values for landscape).

Comment: That is 320 x 480 pixels or 640 x 960 pixels for iPhone 4. That doesn't tell me what dimensions in "points" the PDF should be.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF page size usually matches the common paper sizes (8.5x11 inches is letter) and it should not be based on some fixed screen sizes. Of course you can create pages that match 1 pixel for 1 point (NSMakeRect(0, 0, 320, 480) for example). In this situation you might not have enough space to draw your content or you'll have to rethink the page content (one page content created in the Mac app would fit on 3 or 4 pages created on the iPhone).

Comment: If you are trying to make a PDF that fits content to the shape of an iPhone screen, it is not ideal to use A4 or Letter PDF documents, they both leave extra wasted space. In the case where you are needing to get as much information as you can onto the screen, this is a problem. And before anyone complains, there are legitimate reasons why you would want to squish more content on the screen.

Comment: @iPDFdev I want to create a pdf with custom size. That is it may be 6X7 inch or 4X6 inch when Printed. for these cases how can I create pdf references with cg size. How many points need to make an inch